# Altium: Rules and Query syntax

Tags: components, altium, error

I want to set some rules for certain components. These rules are in the minimum solder mask sliver however I'm stuck on the query.

So far I've written `IsDesignator = U7` but nothing seems to change and I'm still getting error for rule violation.

I'm not sure if my syntax is correct but regardless, using designator to set the rule is inefficient. I want to include the component type instead.

Comment: IsDesignator is a yes/no query. It tells you if the item is a part designator or not (*Is* this a *Designator*). It does not return the actual value of the part designator.

Comment: then can i use IsComponent or ObjectKind = XXX (comp name)?
I'm still new to Query so I'm still catching up with the rules @brhans

Comment: It looks like you would need to use something like InComponent(U7). This should then match any of the bits that make up U7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I handle queries, and I find it to be pretty effective.

In your PCB window, right click on the component you want to identify with a query and right click and and select "Find similiar objects".

This will allow you to narrow down what you are looking for and if you select "Create Expression" at the bottom, it will create an expression in the PCB Filter panel which you can then edit to refine or just copy and paste elsewhere like a rule.

The benefits of this method is that you can see if your query was correct.

So right click your D7 and select Find similar objects and then make sure that **ObjectKind** is set to **same**, and that **Name** is also set to **same**.

Make sure the Create Expression is checked, and Mask is selected from the pulldown (this will highlight the results of your query so you can check if it was correct).

Just a note, if you use this method, the queries can be rather long sometimes, so it is good to review the [Altium Query language](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/Query+Language+Reference) because you can find some useful stuff in there.

Comment: o.0 this will be incredibly useful for complex rules :D